# How do I take a CKEditor UI element and turn it into a JQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('quoteDialog',function(editor){
return{  //... ... code here
    onShow:function(){
        var dialog = this;
        var bg_box = dialog.getContentElement('general','color_box');
        $(bg_box)???
    }
}
});
```

OK, I got the element! But how do I turn it into a JQuery object?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem:

$(bg_box._.inputId);

Comment: what is ._.inputId here? Please I am stuck at the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change CKEditor object (or object array) to JQuery object (or object array)

See example code

CKEditor object list:-
`var elmnts= CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.editable().find('img');`

JQuery object list:- `var elmnts= CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.editable().find('img').$;`